# Returning a result from a query, then a record count of that specific result

Tags: sql

The title is slightly confusing, but basically, I have created a search feature which allows my users to enter search terms.  Say if they entered 'e' it would return answers such as "Leeds, Manchester, Liverpool, Doncaster" etc. Basically, I want something that then checks each of those towns/cities one by one, checks how many bands are registered from those towns/cities, and display say:

** "Leeds - 5 records found"**

It would be easy if you could output multiple queries at once, however, you can't. If somebody knows a way around this I would be very grateful.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Do you know that (in most SQL-based systems) you can use sub-query in `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
select town, count(*) as num
from something
where blah = blah
group by town
```

This should give you a results set like:

```
town      num
----      ----
Leeds     2
Liverpool 3
```

When you use aggregate functions like `max`, `count` and `min` and a `group by` clause, the aggregation applies to the group, in this case, the **town**.

Comment: I'm assuming the num column is listing the amount of records from a designated table in which the records contain the names of the towns?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE citiesWithBand AS
(Select city, count(band) as bandcount
From yourtable
group by city);
```

Then you can do queries:

```
SELECT city, bandcount
FROM citiesWithBand
WHERE city likes '%userinput%';
```

Or you can combine these into a single query:

```
Select city, count(band) as bandcount
From yourtable
WHERE city LIKES '%userinput%'
GROUP BY city;
```